# Creating a nested generic Case Class from a flattened Tuple

Tags: scala, tuples, shapeless, case-class

### Background

I'm working on an API using both Play Framework and Slick.  In an effort to avoid repetitive boiler plate, I want to define my public JSON models without their ID field and wrap them in a `WithId` container.

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class WithId[T](id: Long, item: T)
case class Wiki(name: String, source: Option[String], text: String)

object WithId {
  implicit def withIdRead[T : Reads] : Reads[WithId[T]] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").read[Long] and
    JsPath.read[T]
  )((id, item) => WithId(id, item))

  implicit def withIdWrite[T : Writes] : Writes[WithId[T]] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").write[Long] and
    JsPath.write[T]
  ).apply(unlift(WithId.unapply[T]))
}
```

Thanks to the magic of the `Reads` and `Writes` definition, I can easily handle JSON with or without the id.

```
scala> val rawIdJson = """{"id": 123, "name": "My First Wiki", "text": "This is my first wiki article"}"""
rawIdJson: String = {"id": 123, "name": "My First Wiki", "text": "This is my first wiki article"}

scala> val withId = Json.parse(rawIdJson).validate[WithId[Wiki]].get
withId: model.util.WithId[model.entity.Wiki] = WithId(123,Wiki(My First Wiki,None,This is my first wiki article))

scala> val withIdJson = Json.toJson(withId)
withIdJson: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":123,"name":"My First Wiki","text":"This is my first wiki article"}



scala> val rawJson = """{"name": "My First Wiki", "text": "This is my first wiki article"}"""
rawJson: String = {"name": "My First Wiki", "text": "This is my first wiki article"}

scala> val withoutId = Json.parse(rawJson).validate[Wiki].get
withoutId: model.entity.Wiki = Wiki(My First Wiki,None,This is my first wiki article)

scala> val withoutIdJson = Json.toJson(withoutId)
withoutIdJson: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"name":"My First Wiki","text":"This is my first wiki article"}
```

All well and good.

The problem I now have is that Slick will return rows from the database in the form of tuples or case classes, depending on the query that I'm using. Obviously I could write a lot of pretty straight forward helper methods to transform the tuple/case class into each public model:

```
object Wiki {
  implicit val wikiFmt = Json.format[Wiki]
  def fromRow(row: WikiRow) : WithId[Wiki] = WithId(row.id, Wiki(row.name, row.source, row.text))
  def fromRow(tup: (Long, String, Option[String], String)) : WithId[Wiki] = WithId(tup._1, Wiki(tup._2, tup._3, tup._4))
}
```

... but that is a lot of boilerplate to maintain as the number of public models grow.

### Problem

1. Is there a clean way to take a `Tuple4[Long, String, Option[String], String]` or a `case class WikiRow(id: Long, name: String, source: Option[String], text: String)` and convert it into `WithId[Wiki]` (and vice-versa)?
2. Once I introduce another public model like `case class Template(name: String, description: String)`, can we generalize the solution from #1 to now handle converting a `Tuple3[Long, String, Strong]` into `WithId[Template]` (and vice-versa)?
3. What happens if we throw a field into the private model that isn't used in the public model?  Eg, `case class WikiRow(id: Long, name: String, source: Option[String], text: String, hidden: Boolean)`.  The `hidden` field needs to dropped when going `WikiRow => WithId[Wiki]`, and supplied from another source when going `WithId[Wiki] => WikiRow`.

Comment: How about defining an implicit conversion from the tuple or case class to the `WithId[Model]` class?

Comment: @Yaneeve - How is that different from having the `fromRow` definition for each public model?

I feel like there's some potential magic where `WithId[T]` can take a tuple, lop the head `Long` off of it, and pass the tail of the tuple to `T`'s constructor. I'm just not sure what that magic is.

Comment: Not different at all, except that you don't have to write the invocation explicitly. As for magic, I can't help you unfortunately. Just to remind that magic in this case, is just code that runs that we don't see (or understand). The magician with respect to tuples is [shapless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). I don't understand it enough, but it might help you with what you wish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for questions 1 and 2: yes it is possible with shapeless, as has been suggested. Here is a solution to go from a tuple or row to `WithId[T]`.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class WikiRow(id: Long, name: String, source: Option[String], text: String) 
case class Wiki(name: String, source: Option[String], text: String)
case class WithId[T](id: Long, item: T)

def createWithId[T] = new WithIdCreator[T]

class WithIdCreator[Out] {
  import shapeless._
  import shapeless.ops.hlist.IsHCons
  def apply[In, InGen <: HList, Tail <: HList](in: In)(
    implicit
    genIn: Generic.Aux[In,InGen],
    hcons: IsHCons.Aux[InGen,Long,Tail],
    genOut: Generic.Aux[Out,Tail]
  ): WithId[Out] = {
    val rep = genIn.to(in)
    val id = hcons.head(rep)
    val tail = hcons.tail(rep)
    WithId(id, genOut.from(tail))
  }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class WikiRow
defined class Wiki
defined class WithId
createWithId: [T]=> WithIdCreator[T]
defined class WithIdCreator

scala> createWithId[Wiki](WikiRow(3L, "foo", None, "barbaz"))
res1: WithId[Wiki] = WithId(3,Wiki(foo,None,barbaz))

scala> createWithId[Wiki]((3L, "foo", None: Option[String], "barbaz"))
res2: WithId[Wiki] = WithId(3,Wiki(foo,None,barbaz))

scala> case class Template(name: String, description: String)
defined class Template

scala> createWithId[Template]((3L, "foo", "barbaz"))
res3: WithId[Template] = WithId(3,Template(foo,barbaz))
```

A conversion in the other direction will be more or less analogous.

I see no reason why 3 wouldn't be possible either, but then you will have to rewrite the conversions again to handle dropping or manually supplying parameters.

You can learn more about this in the [shapeless guide](https://github.com/underscoreio/shapeless-guide). All the necessary concepts are explained in there.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I had in mind.  Thanks for the link the guide, it looks like it will be super helpful.