# Reading data into custom case classes in Doobie

Tags: scala, doobie

Let's say I have a `case class X(id: Int, name: String, age: Int)` and some function (in my case, [`withUniqueGeneratedKeys`  in doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/07-Updating.html)) that returns `X`. If I have already defined `X` I am good.

But in my case the core data structure is something like:

```
case class XData(name: String, age: Int)
case class MaterializedX(id: Int, element: XData)
```

And of course I could write a line like `case class X(id: Int, name: String, age: Int)` to create `X` but it would be duplication of logic - whenever something about `XData` changes, I'd have to change the code for `X` as well. Intuitively, it feels like there should be a way to derive `X` from `XData` and `MaterializedX`. This transformation might mean some code, but it would save me lots of future work because I have many item types beyond `X`.

How could this be done? Happy to hear other approaches.

I am using Scala 3.1.2 in case this matters. Thank you!

Edit: Changed title per helpful comment, to make this question easier to understand.

Comment: Is this what you're after?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41746251/19032206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be more clear about the question, I mean what title says is almost completely different from your question description (and what you might be actually looking for). Anyway, in my assumptions, what you need is probably a custom `Read[MaterializedX]` and `Write[MaterializedX]`, as follows:

```scala
implicit val pointMaterializedX: Read[MaterializedX] =
  Read[(Int, String, Int)]
    .map { 
      case (id, name, age) => MaterializedX(id, XData(name, age)) 
    }

implicit val pointWrite: Write[MaterializedX] =
  Write[(Int, String, Int)]
    .contramap { materializedX => 
      (materializedX.id, materializedX.element.name, materializedX.element.age)
    }
```

[More documentations here](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/docs/12-Custom-Mappings.html#deriving-read-and-write-from-existing-instances)

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that Doobie provides tools to make this easy, but I totally agree that the terminology is confusing, I edited above (and added a note that this is added so your answer still makes sense). I tried the solution and it works well!

Answer (score 0):

This works out of the box with doobie. Nested case classes get flattened into one row. The following code compiles without defining any custom decoders.

```scala
case class XData(name: String, age: Int)
case class MaterializedX(id: Int, element: XData)

implicitly[doobie.Read[MaterializedX]]
implicitly[doobie.Write[MaterializedX]]
```